# Doctrine one-to-many association: Issues with composite primary key

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am trying to populate the below one-to-many doctrine association however I am hitting a problem because every <kbd>Customer</kbd> (primary key: `id`) has their visits (primary key: `customer_id` & `visitday`) captured in the <kbd>Visit</kbd> table (I am deriving visitday as the number of days since 1st Jan 2000 before persisting to the database (since datetime objects can not be in the primary key)):

## Entities

```
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Visit", mappedBy="visitday")
     */
    protected $visits;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->visits = new ArrayCollection();
    }
     /* -- */
}


Class Visit
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_id", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $customer;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="visits")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="visitday", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $visitday;

     /* -- */
}
```

My problem is that my <kbd>Customer</kbd> objects are not getting populated with the customer's corresponding visits. I assume this is because doctrine can't see that it should also include its own customer ID in the lookup. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to change $visitday attribute to DateTime. It will be your visit date timestamp. Then customer attribute should be inversed with visits.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="customer_id", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="visits")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $customer;
```

And as an option you could change relation Customer to Visits as ManyToMany. So you wont have duplicate visit dates.

Comment: Thanks @Mike-Kor - although `$visitday` is a categorical variable for what I need. Is there a way I can connect them up so that <kbd>Customer</kbd> can have `visits` populated with an array of the `$visitday` integers of only that customer's visits?

Comment: @Bendy, sorry for late response. You already have $visits variable in Customer entity that represents array of Visit entities via you can access to Customer visit days.